# Debugger is not entering custom attribute class

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-attributes

This is a C# WPF application for a desktop.  I've created a custom attribute class but in debug it never goes in there.  Do I need to add something else to this class?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class Authentication : Attribute, IPrincipal
{
    public Authentication(string id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

And the method is:

```
    [Authentication(SecurityConstants.DataEntrySupervisor)]
    [Authentication(SecurityConstants.DataVerificationClerk)]
    public void Submit(EventObject eventObject)
    {//////////}
```

Answer (score 1):

An attribute is not called by the runtime in any way. It probably does not even get instanciated until you poke around with reflection.

You can look at [SecurityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to do code security with attributes.

Comment: But I had a web app with a custom attribute and I could debug that.  Is there a difference?