# How to debug into decorator method in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, serialization, jsonconvert

I have a class as follows -

```
public class AppSettings
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SomeConverter))]
    public RestApiURL {get; set;}
}
```

and SomeConverter method is like -

```
class SomeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        /*some logic*/
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        /*some logic*/
    }
}
```

When an object of AppSettings is created using IOption, I want to step into SomeConverter converter function through debugger. But it isn't reaching. I think it's not IDE specific.

Comment: add breakpoints in `SomeConverter` and you will be there. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fdf2136-df00-4c46-91d0-db5539aa2ec8/debugging-custom-attributes?forum=netfxtoolsdev

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714541/debugger-is-not-entering-custom-attribute-class

Comment: try to debug my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59075887/2568863, you will see if your code has problem.

Comment: Looks like [`JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Configuration/Config.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs) doesn't use Json.NET, it uses [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0) from `System.Text.Json`.  So your `SomeConverter` will never get instantiated or used.